# implement the URL match in C++

Tags: c++, c

Given a list of URLs, such as a/b/e/f, b/c/d/k/g, s/e/c/d, how to match an input URL to the one in the list, for example, an input c/d should be matched to s/e/c/d, not b/c/d/k/g

Comment: Those don't really look like URLs, and what about s/e/c/d makes it match c/d when b/c/d/k/g doesn't? Because it's on the end?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Why not b/c/d/k/g? Are the "Url"s simply strings? If so simply search it using strstr or one of its derivative (wcsstr, _mbsstr, _mbsstr_l).

Answer (score 0):

Just check if input is equal to input.size() trailing characters in the possible url match.